# How to get the x and y of a program window in Java?

Tags: java, runtime, coordinates, jna, awtrobot

Is there a way for me to get the X and Y values of a window in java? I read that I'll have to use runtime, since java can't mess directly, however I am not so sure of how to do this. Can anyone point me some links/tips on how to get this?

Comment: The screen location of a window? Which Window? The current Java (Swing?) application (in which case getLocationOnScreen() would work) or the window of another unrelated application? If the latter, then I would consider using JNA to solve this.

Comment: Sorry about not being specific... About any other unrelated application.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get the x and y position of "any other unrelated application" you're going to have to query the OS and that means likely using either JNI, JNA or some other scripting utility such as AutoIt (if Windows).  I recommend either JNA or the scripting utility since both are much easier to use than JNI (in my limited experience), but to use them you'll need to download some code and integrate it with your Java application.

**EDIT 1**
I'm no JNA expert, but I do fiddle around with it some, and this is what I got to get the window coordinates for some named window:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;

public class GetWindowRect {

   public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
      User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class,
               W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

      HWND FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

      int GetWindowRect(HWND handle, int[] rect);
   }

   public static int[] getRect(String windowName) throws WindowNotFoundException,
            GetWindowRectException {
      HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, windowName);
      if (hwnd == null) {
         throw new WindowNotFoundException("", windowName);
      }

      int[] rect = {0, 0, 0, 0};
      int result = User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(hwnd, rect);
      if (result == 0) {
         throw new GetWindowRectException(windowName);
      }
      return rect;
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   public static class WindowNotFoundException extends Exception {
      public WindowNotFoundException(String className, String windowName) {
         super(String.format("Window null for className: %s; windowName: %s", 
                  className, windowName));
      }
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   public static class GetWindowRectException extends Exception {
      public GetWindowRectException(String windowName) {
         super("Window Rect not found for " + windowName);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String windowName = "Document - WordPad";
      int[] rect;
      try {
         rect = GetWindowRect.getRect(windowName);
         System.out.printf("The corner locations for the window \"%s\" are %s", 
                  windowName, Arrays.toString(rect));
      } catch (GetWindowRect.WindowNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (GetWindowRect.GetWindowRectException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }      
   }
}
```

Of course for this to work, the JNA libraries would need to be downloaded and placed on the Java classpath or in your IDE's build path.

Comment: how about in Ubuntu or any other Linux desktop?

Comment: User32 is already part of jna-platform library (at least in v5.3.1)

Answer (score 7):

This is easy to do with the help of the end user. Just get them to click on a point in a screen shot.

### E.G.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/** Getting a point of interest on the screen.
Requires the MotivatedEndUser API - sold separately. */
class GetScreenPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
            getScreenSize();
        final BufferedImage screen = robot.createScreenCapture(
            new Rectangle(screenSize));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JLabel screenLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(screen));
                JScrollPane screenScroll = new JScrollPane(screenLabel);
                screenScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
                    (int)(screenSize.getWidth()/2),
                    (int)(screenSize.getHeight()/2)));

                final Point pointOfInterest = new Point();

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                panel.add(screenScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                final JLabel pointLabel = new JLabel(
                    "Click on any point in the screen shot!");
                panel.add(pointLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                screenLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                        pointOfInterest.setLocation(me.getPoint());
                        pointLabel.setText(
                            "Point: " +
                            pointOfInterest.getX() +
                            "x" +
                            pointOfInterest.getY());
                    }
                });

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

                System.out.println("Point of interest: " + pointOfInterest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Typical output

```
Point of interest: java.awt.Point[x=342,y=43]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the party here but will add this to potentially save others a little time. If you are using a more recent version of JNA then `WindowUtils.getAllWindows()` will make this much easier to accomplish.

I am using the most recent stable versions as of this post from the following maven locations:

JNA Platform - net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.2.0

JNA Core - net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.2.0

**Java 8 Lambda** (Edit: rect is a placeholder and will need to be final or effectively final to work in a lambda)

```
//Find IntelliJ IDEA Window
//import java.awt.Rectangle;
final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0); //needs to be final or effectively final for lambda
WindowUtils.getAllWindows(true).forEach(desktopWindow -> {
    if (desktopWindow.getTitle().contains("IDEA")) {
        rect.setRect(desktopWindow.getLocAndSize());
    }
});
```

**Other Java**

```
//Find IntelliJ IDEA Window
Rectangle rect = null;
for (DesktopWindow desktopWindow : WindowUtils.getAllWindows(true)) {
    if (desktopWindow.getTitle().contains("IDEA")) {
         rect = desktopWindow.getLocAndSize();
    }
}
```

Then within a JPanel you can draw a captured image to fit (Will stretch image if different aspect ratios).

```
//import java.awt.Robot;
g2d.drawImage(new Robot().createScreenCapture(rect), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
```

Comment: if I do the above I just get "This platform is not supported, yet" since that is what the code does: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/cc1acdac02e4d0dda93ba01bbe3a3435b8933dab/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/WindowUtils.java#L662