# record a JFrame to a mp4-Video

Tags: java, swing, video, jframe, mp4

Is it possible to record a JFrame as a video in java?
I have a JFrame with a paint()-Method that is called in a Timer.

Now I can generate images from this method in the Frame, but only static ones. I could put them into a list of BufferedImages, but how do I turn this list into a video? Is there an already in Java existing part of the library that could encode this as .mp4? And what do I need to do to access this feature correctly?

Comment: I would like to point you to a SO thread that sort of covers this sort of thing. It may not get you into mp4 but I'm sure you can convert it to do so:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236119/how-to-develop-screen-capture-to-video-application.

Comment: *"It would be very nice if you could give me some advice or maybe a solution of the problem."*  It would be very nice if you could ask a specific question.