# Record SurfaceView animation as video file in android

Tags: android, mp4, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

Last time I've investigated video exporting on android ([Adding watermark bitmap over video in android: 4.3's MediaMuxer or ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358489/adding-watermark-bitmap-over-video-in-android-4-3s-mediamuxer-or-ffmpeg)) it wasn't an easy task.

Here's a scenario: I have a SurfaceView and a drawn BitMap at x,y coordinates. The user taps on the images and drags it around to step 2 and step 3.

[image]

So basically if I record all the x,y through which the touch went, I can replay the animation by drawing the BitMap at a certain framerate.

Now here's the question: is there an easy way to record the "animation" from the SurfaceView into a video file by using android components (no ffmpeg) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, to record the events of the `SurfaceView`, you have to record the screen since the SurfaceView is different and does not draw in the normal view  hierarchy.

> In fact, there are cases where the display data for the SurfaceView isn't even accessible to the app processor - it may be the output of a hardware video pipeline that is composited with the display output of the app processor through a dedicated video overlay. [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/xHIActZZ9PA)

A Creative way can be to capture the screen simultaneously during the event and create a MOV from the bitmaps. Please See : [Create Video From Screen Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236119/how-to-develop-screen-capture-to-video-application#answer-6236324)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing the rendering, you can just render it twice: once to the display, once to a video.  This assumes you *only* want the SurfaceView contents... if you want the other Views as well, then you need to use a screen recording approach.

For a working example, see "Record GL App" in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  For API 21+, you can render onto a [MediaRecorder's Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getSurface()), which will likely be easier if you just want a .mp4 file.