# Create a frame with only a visible border to select screen area

Tags: java, applet, screenshot, frame

I would like to create a frame with only a visible border which is resizable by the user. This application should be able to work as an applet. It should draw a rectangle on the screen which is resizable by the user, upon which it calculates the coordinates of the rectangle on the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpAnS.jpg

[image]

The frame should be similar to what you see in http://www.screenr.com/record.

The first problem I am facing is in making the frame invisible with only the borders being visible.

The second problem is that I need to be able to access my desktop contents through the frame (as shown in the diagram), but with standard frames you cannot access anything behind the frame.

Comment: This is not possible in swing, because it only allows opaque windows. Maybe you can try a set of JWindows?

Comment: I did use JWindows.. And I've got the entire look and feel done... However, one problem still remains that I cant access my desktop through that frame.. I need a way to make that happen.

Comment: Maybe look at `java.awt.Robot`? It can capture the screen.

Comment: Ok yes I did that... I captured the screen, extracted the required coordinates and displayed it correctly on the JWindow... However, there can still be no mouse or keyboard actions on that, like if it were the desktop itself.

Comment: That is why I suggested a *set* of JWindows. One for the top border, one for the left, right and bottom. Maybe some controsl within the bottom one, maybe the ability to drag/drop when clicking on them.

Comment: Well yeah that totally makes sense.. Why did I not think of that! Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

You might use a variant of the code shown on [How to get the x and y of a program window in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091531/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-of-a-program-window-in-java/6092439#6092439).  It obatins a single point, so you'd need to alter it to gain two points (to construct a `Rectangle`).

> This application should be able to work as an applet.

The applet will need to be digitally signed (by you) and trusted (by the user, when prompted) in order to gain screenshots.

Comment: That example really doesn't help me much. Or maybe I cant understand how to use it. For the following reasons:
1 - The example creates a GUI with a title bar and borders. I need a GUI which is only a rectangle and has no visible frame.
2 - The program takes a screenshot of the desktop and asks user to interact with that. I want my program to work on the desktop itself. Not with a screenshot.

You could see http://www.screenr.com/record. The visible rectangle that pops up is something very similar to what I want. Im sorry if I'm being ambiguous, I cant find the correct words to explain.

Comment: Is there no answer to my question? I used your code, but I cant seem to make the applet title window go away.. Furthermore I cant seem to understand how to access my desktop through it..