# JNA Cant find part of the library

Tags: java, netbeans, jna

This is my first time using JNA, and its been hard but great at the same.

Trying to follow this code example [How to get the x and y of a program window in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091531/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-of-a-program-window-in-java)

I imported:

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;
```

Which I need for this part of the code

```
HWND FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);
int GetWindowRect(HWND handle, int[] rect);
```

Problem is the second import is not found, and I have not been able to find a reason. I am using Netbeans, incase it matters.

Note: I downloaded latest version of JNA.jar and if you do edit my question please let me know what you edit to fix it myself next time.

Comment: did you download `platform.jar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the GitHub's [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) page again, and download `platform.jar` also. and add it to the library.. :)

Comment: Better step is to go to link provided by Asif, and type ctrl + f and into the find window you type: platform.jar and search until you find the independent download link for platform. It should be named platform-versionnumber.jar