# AWT ROBOT - I can't find an element

Tags: java, selenium, awtrobot

I'm creating a application with WebDriver API for make non regression tests.

At a moment, I have to find an element (fic) on my computer (with the Windows's navigator), and i can't (or I just fail :P) do this with WebDriver.

So I'm searching for and I've find awt.Robot . But this robot just click on a [px,px] position.. How can I say 'Click on the search bar, click on the element with the name "A", click on the "OK" button ?' (All of these elements are  Windows's elements.)
Thank you for help !

Comment: Webdriver can't do this, as you've found, because it can only interact with web-browser elements, as in those elements rendered within a web-browser. Using the `Robot()` class is the correct way to go but you'll have to do it the hard way and provide the pixel locations of where you want to click.

Comment: Ok I've find a way, THX !! [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091531/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-of-a-program-window-in-java) But now how i can press '\' for make a path? When I do : "robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH); " that make a error : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code", but woth the code "robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLON); " it works.. WHY ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (for me) is to use [this exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091531/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-of-a-program-window-in-java) to get the position+dimension of the window by its name.

> `int[0] = X`
>   `int[1] = Y`
>   `int[2] = width`
>   `int[3] = height`

In a second time, I use the awt.Robot with moveMouse() at the good position and click() or place the good characters.

For the '/' slash, I use :

> `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);`
>   `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);`
>   `robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);`
>   `robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);`

I hope this helps someone.