# Can Java control position of windows from other programs?

Tags: java, windows, screen, move

I am wondering is it possible somehow to move another window on the screen to different location using Java ?

Example: I would like to move this window to the marked location.
[image: example]

Comment: Probably not. That would be a clear security concern if that were possible.

Comment: So, given the function [`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) from the WinAPI and something like [this JNA example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091531/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-of-a-program-window-in-java/6091597#6091597), I would say, generally yes

Comment: [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) provides a [`User32#SetWindowPos`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32.html#SetWindowPos-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND-int-int-int-int-int-) function

Answer (score 0):

Interfering with other programs is usually only allowed with superuser access (root). If you do not mind executing your program as root, there are possibilities, but they are certainly not cross-platform, so you would have to write a version for every OS around. I would not use java for such things.

Also, the answer about using the Windows API will not work, since you will not be able to get the window handle of a different process. Just check the documentation:

> SetWindowPos  Changes the size, position, and Z order **of a child,
>   pop-up, or top-level window**.

Java APIs will not help you out here.