# How do you get output from command in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a project in Java where I am trying to get the size of the terminal window. I have found that `stty size` returns the size in rows and columns which I am fine with.

My problem is to get the values using Java. So far I have this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("stty", "size");
try {
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This outputs:

```
[I@6ce253f1
```

However, when I just run `stty size` on my own, I get `30 213`. I assume it is some sort of encoding issue but I am not sure.

Comment: [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6091597/4725875) may assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("stty", "size");
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
processBuilder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
try {
  ...
```

Then you get an error message which is written to the error channel, too. And the input channel is set to the same input channel the Java process is using.