# Linux: how to get a list of all visible windows

Tags: java, linux, gnome

Disclaimer: *I know there is a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188484/windows-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-visible-windows) on this topic.*

I am trying to get exactly the same result that NoozNooz42 described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188484/windows-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-visible-windows). However [mdma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3238193/882160) answer doesn't fit my needs, because I'm interested in doing the same on linux. Preferrably with gnome, if it matters. So using JNA with user32 library is not a option here (*or is it?*).

Any suggestions will be great, I couldn't find almost anything on the topic.

P.S.
The only thing I have found is wmctrl command (I could call and parse it in java eventually) that lists windows but doesn't give me any information about the z-order.

Update:
It would be perfect if I could get a notification/callback when the z-order changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use xprop, it shows window properties. List of windows in z-order is in property `_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING` of the root window:

```
xprop -root | grep '_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW)'
```

Output should look like this:

```
_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW): window id # 0x2000003, 0x4000004,
0x1c00004, 0x1c00030, 0x1c00033, 0x2e00004
```

Later you can get more info about particular windows with:

```
xprop -id <id>
```

or

```
xwininfo -id <id>
```

Comment: Very good answer, thank you! +1 for this, however I'm still hoping for pure java solution

Comment: Please see my update on the question. Do you know about anything that would give me a notification on z-order change?

Comment: `xev -root` will show all the changes in root window properties. Just filter after _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING.

Comment: That is awesome. I am only starting to imagine what are my possibilities now. Is this a standard package in all common linux distributions?

Comment: I am not sure. It wasn't standard in Ubuntu few releases ago though now it is. Btw it is x11-utils .

Comment: `xprop -root _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING` filters it without grep.