# Focus an application and simulate keypresses

Tags: java, user-interface, focus

My problem is what class/method do I use such that by pressing a gui button an application X gains focus. basically switching between applications so.

Answer (score 0):

[`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) can be used to generate keypresses. I am not aware of any Java API which will allow you to focus another application's windows. You will probably have to resort to using native code called via JNI. Here is an example of [enumerating windows using JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188484/windows-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-visible-windows) that could provide a staritng point.