# Selecting a window behind a JFrame

Tags: java, windows, swing

Alright, to give you a bit of background, I have a JFrame that I've manipulated to be a full screen transparent overlay when the user types a keystroke on the keyboard.

**The goal is I want the user to select any previously opened window (so could be the web browser you're using now) to then further manipulate with my program.** I have the overlay working with a global keystroke managed with JIntellitype and Swing's nifty extended state method for full screen...ness.

**The problem I have is that even with the really nice-looking overlay that appears the way I want, you cannot select any of your windows because the JFrame is over them.** I need it to be like what [ScreenCloud](http://screencloud.net/) has with their screenshot selection (look at 0:19 on their video), but the user just needs to click on a window when the overlay/message appears.

I'm looking into [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) for getting the window sizes and other info for later use in my application. I'm open for any ideas on how to go about this. *Worst case scenario would be that I do something that you would see on your CTRL-ALT-Tab window switcher for selecting a window.*

**Note**: If it helps at all, I'm using a TrayIcon for my application to be centered around, which then calls and creates JFrames and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future, if anyone (which I doubt anyone) runs into this problem, have JNA grab the rectangle for each window and in the order in which they're layered (e.g. "File Manager" - (0,0)(250,250) , "Eclipse" - (0,0)(1920,1080) -- this saying the window "File Manager" is on top). Then have the JFrame listen for a mouse click event on its frame; Use those coordinates to find any collisions with the rectangles you generated with JNA. Code example for those who would like it (the JNA side of it):

```
public static List<WindowInfo> getWindows() {
    final List<WindowInfo> inflList = new ArrayList<WindowInfo>();
    final List<Integer> order = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int top = User32.instance.GetTopWindow(0);
    while (top!=0) {
        order.add(top);
        top = User32.instance.GetWindow(top, User32.GW_HWNDNEXT);
    }
    User32.instance.EnumWindows(new WndEnumProc()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean callback(int hWnd, int lParam)
        {
            if (User32.instance.IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) {
                RECT r = new RECT();
                User32.instance.GetWindowRect(hWnd, r);
                if (r.left>-32000) {     // minimized
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    User32.instance.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, buffer, buffer.length);
                    String title = Native.toString(buffer);
                    inflList.add(new WindowInfo(hWnd, r, title));
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }, 0);
    Collections.sort(inflList, new Comparator<WindowInfo>()
            {
        @Override
        public int compare(WindowInfo o1, WindowInfo o2) {
            return order.indexOf(o1.hwnd)-order.indexOf(o2.hwnd);
        }
            });
    return inflList;
}
public static interface WndEnumProc extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback {
    boolean callback (int hWnd, int lParam);
}

public static interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary
{
    final User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary ("user32", User32.class);
    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class,
               W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    boolean EnumWindows (WndEnumProc wndenumproc, int lParam);
    boolean IsWindowVisible(int hWnd);
    int GetWindowRect(int hWnd, RECT r);
    void GetWindowTextA(int hWnd, byte[] buffer, int buflen);
    int GetTopWindow(int hWnd);
    int GetWindow(int hWnd, int flag);

    HWND FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

    final int GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
}
```

Note as this is for Windows (as seen by the User32 class). The class *WindowInfo* holds the rectangle, title, and handle for each window. This is then thrown back to the MouseListener.

**EDIT**: Found it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3238193/3502776